# deleting a row in dbvisualizer

Tags: sql

I would like to delete this one in the db visualizer and not sure if I am writing the correct syntax:

[image]

I also see that the `idsapusertype` 25 is also linked to idsapusertypedetails 75 and 76. 
Can I use this one?

```
delete from sap_user_type_details where idsapusertypedetails = 77
```

or

```
delete from sap_user_type_details where idsapusertype = 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `delete from sap_user_type_details where idsapusertypedetails = 77` since `idsapusertype = 25` condition matches other records.

For best results, `delete from sap_user_type_details where idsapusertypedetails = 77 and idsapusertype = 25`

Comment: ah ok you can mix the two then?

Comment: but i have problems the other value was still there.. and if I click on it, the software hangs:-(

Comment: @tintin how do you mean the other value was there ?

Comment: thanks for helping. I was able to figure it out. I've seen that there are other tables which are link so I also have to delete it first. Now it's working.